# What car would I need to buy (secondhand) to replace my currently wrecked BMW 318i motor?

Tags: engine, motors

Okay so I currently have a BMW e46 (318i) and i took it to my mechanic, motors wrecked etc etc. He suggested a cheaper alternative to fixing the motor would be to buy a whole new car (max 5k, second hand) which has a good engine/motor and he would replace one with the other. Would it matter what type of BMW I get or would it have to be the same series and year etc?

Comment: You might have a better chance just purchasing the motor itself. eBay is showing me multiple 318i motors for under $1000 USD.

Comment: Can you count on them being reliable? Also, would I buy a complete engine? If so, would any 318i engine fit?

Comment: Many breakers yards will provide a short warranty with a second hand engine on an exchange basis.  You can also buy reconditioned engines which are more expensive but give a longer waranty.  Out of interest, what is wrong with your engine?  You may be able to buy just a "bottom end" if the head is alright or just a cylinder head if that's the problem.

Comment: What year is the car?